# Render PDF attachment in salesforce on the fly

Tags: salesforce

I have a scenario where I need to fetch a attachment from web server into Salesforce on the fly for review.

Can anybody suggest a best practice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a combination of blob types in apex 
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_blob.htm

and renderAs="pdf" for visual force
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_additional_render_pdf.htm#pages_compref_additional_render_pdf